# General control problem with nonlinear performance index with integral and a scrap value

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

I have an optimal control problem with a following general form for the performance index

$J = \phi_{1}[x(t_f)] + \sqrt {\phi_{2}[x(t_f)] + \int_{t_0}^{t_f}L[x(t)] dt},$

subject to

$\dot{x}(t)=g(x(t),u(t))$, $x(t_0)=x_0$ (fixed), $x(t_f)$ (free)

where $x(t)$ is the state variable, $0 \leq u(t)\leq 1$ is the control variable, $\phi_{1}[x(t_f)]$ and $\phi_{2}[x(t_f)]$ are some functions of the scrap value (final state).

How should I start solving this optimal control problem? Can I write directly the Hamiltonian for this problem or do I have to transform the performance index into some other form before I can write down the Hamiltonian for this problem?

If so, how would you suggest to transform it?

Answer (score 1):

If the $\phi_1$ is positive definite and you seek a minimizer then define

$$
J' := \sqrt{\phi_1(x_f)^2+\phi_2(x_f)+\int_{t_0}^{t_f} L(x)dt}.  
$$
By the triangle inequality $J' \leq J$ and $J'$ is minimized whenever $J'^2$ is minimized. The Hamiltonian is now standard.

Comment: Because of the inequality, however, I am not sure if I minimize $J'$, I have also minimized $J$.

Comment: That's why you need to assume $\phi_1$ is positive definite.

Comment: I really like the idea if this trick can be used for my problem. From physical constraints, I know that $\phi_1$ is positive definite as well as $\phi_2$. However, $J^2-J'^2=2a\sqrt {\phi_2 + \int_{t_0}^{t_f} {L(x)dt}}$. Hence, I do not see how $J$ is minimized by minimizing $J'$ because you have this extra term.

Comment: Suppose $J'$ is minimized. What can you say about $\phi_2+\int_{t_0}^{t_f}L(x)dt$? Hint: put $K(x) = \phi_2+\int_{t_0}^{t_f}L(x)dt$. You now have $J' = \sqrt{\phi^2_1 + K}$ and $J = \phi_1 + \sqrt{K}$. You've already pointed out that $J^2$ has the 'extra' term $2\phi_1\sqrt{K}$, but you haven't considered what the minimization of $J'$ means about this term (assuming $\phi_1$ is positive definite).

Comment: If this implication is true, then it should also be true for a static optimizaton case, where x is just a scalar variable. It can easily be shown with a conterexample that minimizing $J'$ does not imply the minimization of $J$. Lets say $\phi_1(x)=x^2$ and $K(x)=1/x$. We can easily see that the extreme points  for J and J' are different.

Answer (score 1):

You can also reformulate your problem by adding a new DE:

$$\dot{x}_J=L(x),\quad x_J(0)=0.$$

In this way, your $J$ can be written as 
$$J=\psi(x(t_f))$$ 
with $\psi(x(t_f))=\phi_1(x(t_f))+\sqrt{\phi_2(x(t_f))+x_J(x(t_f))}$. Such cost functional is said to be in the Mayer form.